# If demons or supernatural beings were real, what weapons would hunters have other than a sword?

Tags: weapons

If for example vampires were real, and the church would hire anyone dumb or brave enough to kill those things, what type of equipment should they bring?
Honestly, I was going to take the trick weapon designs from Bloodborne since the weapons fit the theme of butchering non-human beings (and also normal humans) in the most inhumane way possible. But before I think of anything crazy, I would like to know if there are any normal weapons which befit butchering monsters.
The time in my world is probably when people started making rifles and revolvers, but not so advanced as to have had automatic weapons, such as assault rifles (1850 or so).

Comment: It's a lookup table.  First column is name of monster. Second column is vulnerable to. For example, Vampire, Wooden stake through heart, and so on for your setting's specific vampires.

Comment: It depends. In some myths they can only be hurt by some kinds of weapon. But even if any weapon can hurt them, ask yourself: what weapons would you use to kill people and animals? Then work from there.

Comment: Like the other commenters mention, you really have to provide more details about these monsters and/or supernatural beings. As it stands, anyone can imagine any type of either, and base their answer on any existing or imaginary vulnerability, resulting in a potentially endless *list* of answers, which is explicitly off-topic. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Money doesn't grow on trees, and good churches typically seek to minimize needless deaths. The church will not waste money throwing stupid people at the problem. They will only hire monster hunters who appear capable. I would expect the church to ask each applicant about their methods and armaments, and to politely turn away anybody who is patently unprepared, foolhardy, or unequal to the prey.

Comment: I was the final VTC and I'd like to explain why. You're asking us how to combat monsters that aren't at all defined. You see, vampires (etc.) *don't exist.* Consequently, there's no way to identify useful weapons based on history or science. And since we don't answer Qs about 3rd party/commercial worlds or brainstorm, we're stuck. We'll help you define those monsters! We'll help you identify good weapons based on your world's rules! But you need to bring your due diligence. You even said, "for example..." that opens the door to *everything.* You must be specific here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**The right ones**

Generally speaking, if you go out to hunt a grizzly bear, you will take a gun. This was true even in the time period you are set in, when firearms were generally only single shot. Why might this be?

While it makes for a cathartic and rewarding gameplay loop, fighting a monster up close is tantamount to suicide. A gigantic predatory monster will not repeat a set moveset which you can dodge or parry, then chip away at its healthbar. It will grab you, pin you down, and crush your skull and neck, like most predators do. Or, perhaps, it will simply break your spine with a single blow if its strong enough. Unaltered, generic humans, even with weapons and armor, nearly always lack the capability to kill a larger, stronger animal, at least, before it can kill you. This is further compounded by the fact that these are not mere animals, but supernatural beings. Vampires and Demons are undoubtedly more dangerous than a cougar or lion, and worst of all, smarter. If you thought fighting something the size of a gorilla in a close quarters fight was challenging, it's undoubtedly worse if it's your intellectual equal (or better, because demons and vampires probably learnt quite a bit after existing for centuries to millennia), has a big scary demon sword of its own, and can summon the fires of hell to burn its foes.

So, how do you survive these encounters? Careful planning and use of mankind's great equaliser; technology and numbers.

Weapon-wise, concerning the time period, the Sharps Rifle would be terrific. Extreme long-range accuracy, and a powerful .52 caliber bullet meant for bringing down buffalo, as well as a relatively quick breech loading system make it useful for bringing down, or seriously maiming a victim from a distance, where its claws and teeth can't hurt you. With you and seven friends all aiming at the same target, even more so. I feel that the regenerative capabilities of a vampire would do little for two .50 caliber projectile going through its skull. Should a creature get close, coach guns and pikes, and studded trench clubs and knives, for grappling. Padded gambesons going up to the neck to dissuade something from simply tearing out your throat and providing ample protection/mobility.

Though its use would be limited, a cannon filled with grapeshot could be used as a potent ambush weapon. Shelling a location known to house a beast with mortars would also have select applications. Expensive, but effective.

You would also ideally kill your quarry in the most pragmatic and easy way possible. Vampire hiding out in an old house? Burn it to the ground during daylight. Demon in the old mine? Collapse it with dynamite. Leave dead hogs stuffed with poison to kill or seriously weaken your prey. Every time you must directly face the enemy, you potentially face your own demise.

Answer (score 3):

How long have these monsters been known?

If they are new, you bring all sorts of things to eliminate by experiment what doesn't work, so you can use stuff that works.   True, you're likely to develop superstitions where an effective weapon is tainted by being wielded by an incompetent, but it's improbable that you can run  large sample sizes. (Bear in mind that vampire is a name we would bestow after seeing a monster's weakness, not vice versa.)

If they've been around a while, see the results of above from prior generations.

As for what those results are, you are free as a bird.  If you want to decree that they are all vulnerable to blunt wooden weapons like children's toys, you can do so.